# How to find x intercept for intersection of two curves in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

```html
df1=read.csv("file1.csv")
df2=read.csv("file2.csv") 
ggplot(df1, aes(x,y))+geom_line()+geom_line(aes(df2$x, df2$y))
df2$x[abs(df2$y-df2$x)<0.001 & df2$x>5 & df2$x<7)]
```

I had csv data which I imported to R environment as a dataframe. Then I I overlay the two dataframes on a plot using ggplot. I need to find the points where intersection of the curves will be located between x=5 and x=7.5. Can you help?
The last line of code I used as shown in the code snippet didn't show me any value but I can see the intersection in the plot.
[image: the 2 plots overlaid using ggplot]

Comment: some sample data (using `dput`) would be nice...

Comment: I had edited the question and provided the sample data

Answer (score 3):

You just need to find the points where your x values (hereinafter called `x`) are within your specified range, and each of your y values (`y1` and `y2` respectively) are equal. A naive approach might be

```
which(x <= xmax & x >= xmin & y1 == y2)
```

However, for the reasons detailed in [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal), that won't always work out. However, you can do something like this:

```r
# Create an dataframe:
x <- seq(0, 10, 0.01)
y1 <- sin(x)
y2 <- cos(x)
df <- data.frame(x = x, y1 = y1, y2 = y2)
# Let's plot the curves
# I like to use the colorblind-friendly palette from
# Wong, Bang. 2011. "Points of view: Color blindness." Nature Methods 8:441.
wong_palette <- c("#e69f00", "#56b4e9")
# Plot the first curve
plot(x, y1, type = "l", xlab = "V1", ylab = "V2", col = wong_palette[1])
# Add the second
lines(x, y2, col = wong_palette[2])
# What are the intersections?
equivalent <- function(x, y, tol = 0.005) abs(x - y) < tol
xmin <- 3
xmax <- 8
intersection_indices <- which(equivalent(y1, y2) & x >= xmin & x <= xmax)
x[intersection_indices]
#> [1] 3.93 7.07
points(x[intersection_indices], y1[intersection_indices])
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Note I did this with sample data I created myself, as your provided code snippet isn't quite sufficient to provide sample data. For future reference to write great questions, you may want to check out [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).